# Sed manipulating text

Tags: sed

I'm a novice in programming. I'm trying to remove `*` character in my text file using `sed` but to no avail, and keep getting this :

> sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `*'.

Please help?Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that '*' is a special shell character and will be processed before the sed command. To combat this, use the escape character '\' before the '*' so it will be ignored by the shell and processed as a part of the sed command:

```
sed 's/\*//g' fileName
```

Comment: Er...the code works, but the explanation is wrong. Inside single quotes, the shell does not expand `*`. The problem is that `*` has special meaning for sed (the Kleene star -- `a*` will match an arbitrary number of `a`s, for example), and if you want sed to treat it as a literal asterisk, it needs to be escaped.

Comment: @Wintermute You're absolutely right. Thank you for that clarification.

Comment: Guys, the code did not work for me though. i have recheck the text file using grep '*' file name and the * stil exist. Help?

Comment: ok guys problem is solved LOL! i forget to make a new file of it as follow: sed 's/\*//g' fileName >newfilename.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can also escape the shell meta characters by character class [] 
in sed

```
sed 's/[*]//g' filename
```